# Android sockets - One server multiple Clients

Tags: android

I have to create a simple Teacher and students app .

**Step one :**

Teacher create a simple server .
students connect to server that created by teacher .

**Step two :**

Teacher say something ( it does not matter what is that exactly )
Students only receive teacher's message .

I need a **simple tutorial or sample code** .

any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is ServerSocket on the teacher side. But you will not want your users to handle all IP address, socket port and similar low level issues. Look for a proper session handling protcol or use a google service like Nearby. If you still want to use ServerSocket look into here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html

Comment: Thank you but im new in socket can you help me some more ?

Answer (score 1):

As your question points, You need to create a chat app. Here are some tutorial for chat application, [1](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/),[2](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-2/),[3](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397) these will help to understand the basics to create chat application in andorid.